# Excel VBA: How to use Dictionary between two workbooks for Vlookup?

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

I have a worksheet (in my desktop) which have over 13.000 rows with duplicate data which I add 3 new column with vlookup from another file (called ProductList) located on sharedrive. I tried to use Dictionary but I don't know how can I add a different workbook to my code? I add ProductList to my file as Sheet2 and successfully run the code.

```
Sub ckv()

Dim Rng As Range, Dn As Range, n As Long, Tic As Object, ray As Variant

'This is normally my ProductList workbook, which has 4 columns

With Sheets("Sheet2")
ray = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Resize(, 4)
End With

Set Tic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
Tic.CompareMode = vbTextCompare

For n = 2 To UBound(ray, 1)
Tic(ray(n, 1)) = n

Next

'And this is my file in my desktop
With Sheets("Sheet1")
Set Rng = .Range(.Range("I2"), .Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

For Each Dn In Rng
If Tic.Exists(Dn.Value) Then

 Dn.Offset(, -2) = ray(Tic(Dn.Value), 2)
 Dn.Offset(, -1) = ray(Tic(Dn.Value), 3)
 Dn.Offset(, 1) = ray(Tic(Dn.Value), 4)

  End If

  Next Dn

  End With

End Sub
```

regards

Comment: You should open the sharedrive workbook to build the [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4(v=vs.84).aspx) with unique Key and some Value, for multiple Values you should designate a separation character to append more values to a Key. Once Dictionary built, you can close the sharedrive file and use the Dictionary to retrieve values. The way you use Dictionary is strange, especially no sample data structure shown.

Comment: hello PatricK,sorry for late reply. I found this code from a forum and updated according to my workbook. My Dictionary knowledge is zero. But from your comment I understood that I have to open ProductList so Dictionary could work.